# Subclass QPushbutton with different args

Tags: python, pyside

How can I subclass the QPushbutton in Pyside but require an arg. In my example I need the arg to be a list of ints [0,0,0].

My goal is to make it so i can create MyButton like this:

```
# GOAL
MyButton([0,255,0])
```

When the arguement containing the list of values is passed in, it should set the value self._data. I'm not sure if i have this setup correctly, so any corrections are appreciated.

```
class MyButton(QtGui.QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._data = stuff

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data

    @data.setter
    def data(self, value):
        self._data = value


MyButton([0,255,0])
```

Updated: I noticed though when i pass that value into my Init it doesn't appear to trigger the setter for that property?? Why is that? If you test the code below, you'll see the color of the button isn't set when it's instantiated. How do i fix that?

```
import os
import sys
import json
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui


class QColorSwatch(QtGui.QPushButton):

    colorClicked = QtCore.Signal(list)
    colorChanged = QtCore.Signal(list)

    def __init__(self, stuff, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QColorSwatch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._color = stuff
        self.setMaximumWidth(22)
        self.setMaximumHeight(22)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.pressed.connect(self.color_clicked)

    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

    @color.setter
    def color(self, value):
        self._color = value
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        pixmap.fill(QtGui.QColor(value[0], value[1], value[2]))
        self.setIcon(pixmap)
        self.colorChanged.emit(value)
        # swatch.setIconSize(pixmap.size() - QtCore.QSize(6,6))

    def color_clicked(self):
        self.colorClicked.emit(self.color)



class ExampleWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(ExampleWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(300, 200)

        self.ui_swatch = QColorSwatch([255,0,0])

        # main layout
        main_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.setContentsMargins(5,5,5,5)
        main_layout.setSpacing(5)
        main_layout.addWidget(self.ui_swatch)

        main_widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        main_widget.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_widget)

        # Signals
        self.ui_swatch.colorClicked.connect(self.color_clicked)
        self.ui_swatch.colorChanged.connect(self.color_changed)

    def color_clicked(self, col):
        print 'CLICKED:', col
        self.ui_swatch.color = [255,0,0]

    def color_changed(self, col):
        print 'CHANGED:', col


def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = ExampleWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put `stuff` as a parameter.

```
class MyButton(QtGui.QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, stuff, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyButton, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._data = stuff

    @property
    def data(self):
        return self._data

    @data.setter
    def data(self, value):
        self._data = value

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWin = MyButton([0,255,0])
    print(mainWin.data)
    mainWin.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Update:

You have to use self.color to use the setter.

```
class QColorSwatch(QtGui.QPushButton):

    colorClicked = QtCore.Signal(list)
    colorChanged = QtCore.Signal(list)

    def __init__(self, stuff, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QColorSwatch, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._color = None
        self.color = stuff
        self.setMaximumWidth(22)
        self.setMaximumHeight(22)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.pressed.connect(self.color_clicked)

    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

    @color.setter
    def color(self, value):
        self._color = value
        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        pixmap.fill(QtGui.QColor(value[0], value[1], value[2]))
        self.setIcon(pixmap)
        self.colorChanged.emit(value)
        # swatch.setIconSize(pixmap.size() - QtCore.QSize(6,6))

    def color_clicked(self):
        self.colorClicked.emit(self.color)
```

Comment: i noticed it doesn't appear to trigger my data to set the color of the button correctly though.